# How can I move the position of a boxview depending on the platform in XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

this is my code XAML for the boxview  it is inside an absolutelayout

```
<BoxView  BackgroundColor="#04388C" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,.1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"/>
```

the absolutelayout.layoutbounds showing over there is for my ANDROID device but for the IOS i need it to be "0,0,1,.1" to be at the top

let me place a screenshot ↓↓↓↓↓ click the link for the image

the blue box on the bottom on the screen on IOS i need it to be at the top

[the blue box on the bottom on the screen on IOS i need it to be at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Re7V.png)

Answer (score 1):

In XAML:

```
<BoxView  x:Name="MyBoxView"/>
```

In Code-Behind constructor:

```
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(MyBoxView, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(MyBoxView, new Rectangle(0, Device.OnPlatform(iOS:0, Android:1, WinPhone:0), 1, 0.1));
```

Note: Device.OnPlatform(iOsValue, androidValue, WinValue) sets different values according to running platform.

**Update:**
The code above will give us the following warning message:

*`[System.Obsolete("OnPlatform is obsolete as of version 2.3.4. Please use switch(RuntimePlatform) instead.")]`*

To address this issue we can use this code instead:

```
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(MyBoxView, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
{
     case Device.Android:
     {
         AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(MyBoxView, new Rectangle(0, 1, 1, 0.1));
         break;
     }
     case Device.iOS:
     {
          AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(MyBoxView, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 0.1));
          break;
     }
}
```

Comment: showing this message Device.OnPlatform (T, T, T)' is obsolete: 'Use switch (RuntimePlatform) instead any other option?

Answer (score 1):

XAML only:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <OnPlatform x:Key="layoutBounds" x:TypeArguments="Rectangle">
    <On Platform="iOS">0,0,1,.1</On>
    <On Platform="Android, UWP">0,1,1,.1</On>
  </OnPlatform>
</ResourceDictionary>
...
<AbsoluteLayout>
  <BoxView BackgroundColor="Blue" 
           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="{StaticResource layoutBounds}" 
           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```